# FAQ Addendum: "typical" Salary/Hourly rates are off topic

Tags: discussion, status-completed, faq-content

Something I really should have brought up in [FAQ Proposal: Off topic areas](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345/faq-proposal-off-topic-areas) is that **questions about average expected salary/hourly rates/how much should I charge are always too localized.**

As typified by questions like https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/how-much-to-charge-as-a-freelance-programmer#question we just can't answer these questions, and if we can, the answers won't help many people or for very long; the answers vary from city to city, year to year, and they're *already* very limited by job type and skills.

So I propose to add the following to our [FAQ section on off-topic questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq#what-questions-are-off-topic-here):

> - "What salary/hourly rate should I look for? How much should I charge for X?"
>
>   - Questions regarding salary are too localized to the city, timeframe, job sector and specific skills. Answers to these questions become quickly outdated and just aren't helpful to others.
>   - For general salary hunting tips, see [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)

Comment: Agree; I'm not sure how any of us missed adding that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No objections? Anyone? Bueller?

***Sold!*** This will be added to the [FAQ](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq).