# May I ask what the going rate is for a particular position?

Tags: support, on-topic-definition, close-reasons, scope

I tried https://www.glassdoor.com/index.htm but it wasn't helpful for this particular position.

I checked https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and [FAQ - What questions can I ask here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320/faq-what-questions-can-i-ask-here) but didn't find the guidance I needed.

Comment: You could ask how you can find out a the going rate when Glassdoor.com is not helpful.

Answer (score 6):

From one of the places you linked: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> What questions are off topic here?
>
> - Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies
> - Questions asking for advice on what to do (including reviewing resumes, CVs, cover letters, e-mails, asking for legal advice, as well
>     as **specific salaries**, billing rates, market worth, etc.)
> - Questions that focus on ranting about problems rather than trying to solve them
> - Questions that aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format (see also Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for information on how to
>     ask a subjective question suitable for the Stack Exchange format)

the salary depends on exact job description, years of experience, location, how hard it is to fill. And it will change next year.

Answer (score 5):

There is no "going rate" for a position. Despite popular belief, it's almost entirely dependent on the company and how well your skill set matches their needs.

There may be exceptions for legally regulated wages (tea pickers in India) or where there is an effective monopoly supplier with a collective agreement (the NHS in the UK), but in general I'd say this is too company specific for us to give an answer.